# ArrayList with customArrayAdapter only showing 1 list

Tags: java, android, json, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

I have created arraylist with a customArrayAdapter and while using mock data, the list was visible on the screen without any error but when I replaced the mock data with JsonObject where the json response is hardcoded as string value in the java file then I found all the data are correctly showing in the list but only 1 list item is displayed in the screen instead of 15 as the response contains 15 JsonArray objects.
I have used the for loop for looping through the JsonArray but I don't know what's the error?

[image]

> MainActivity.Java :

```
package com.example.anybookinfo;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ListView bookListView = findViewById(R.id.bookListView);
        ArrayList<BookStore> bookStoreArrayList = HTTTP_REQUEST.readFromJson(HTTTP_REQUEST.jsonResponse);

        BookAdapter bookAdapter = new BookAdapter(this, bookStoreArrayList);

        bookListView.setAdapter(bookAdapter);
    }
}
```

> HTTP_Request.java :

```
package com.example.anybookinfo;

import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public final class HTTTP_REQUEST {
public static ArrayList<BookStore> readFromJson(String jsonObject) {
        ArrayList<BookStore> currentBookStore = new ArrayList<>();
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(jsonObject)) {
            return null;
        }
        try {
            JSONObject root = new JSONObject(jsonObject);
            JSONArray items = root.getJSONArray("items");
            for (int i = 0; i < items.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject currentBook = items.getJSONObject(i);
                JSONObject volumeInfo = currentBook.getJSONObject("volumeInfo");
                String fTitle = volumeInfo.getString("title");
                String lTitle = volumeInfo.getString("subtitle");
                JSONArray author = volumeInfo.getJSONArray("authors");
                String authorName = author.getString(0);
                int PageCount = volumeInfo.getInt("pageCount");
                JSONObject saleInfo = currentBook.getJSONObject("saleInfo");
                JSONObject listPrice = saleInfo.getJSONObject("listPrice");
                double amount = listPrice.getDouble("amount");
                String currencyCode = listPrice.getString("currencyCode");
                JSONObject searchInfo = currentBook.getJSONObject("searchInfo");
                String textSnippet = searchInfo.getString("textSnippet");
                BookStore bookStore = new BookStore(fTitle, lTitle, authorName, textSnippet, PageCount, amount, currencyCode);
                currentBookStore.add(bookStore);
            }
        } catch (JSONException j) {
            Log.e("readFromJson Error", "error in reading the json response", j);
        }
        return currentBookStore;
    }
 public static final String jsonResponse = "  //the json response code is here " ;
}
```

The actual json response link which is hardcoded : 
https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=Inner%20Engineering%20:%20a%20yogi%27s%20guide%20to%20joy&maxResults=15

> LogCat Error :

```
01-24 23:18:46.030 3693-3703/? E/art: Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
01-24 23:18:46.243 3693-3693/? E/readFromJson Error: error in reading the json response
    org.json.JSONException: No value for listPrice
        at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:389)
com.example.anybookinfo.HTTTP_REQUEST.readFromJson(HTTTP_REQUEST.java:58)
        at com.example.anybookinfo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
```

> The MainActivity.java:18 Line Contain :

```
ArrayList<BookStore> bookStoreArrayList = HTTTP_REQUEST.readFromJson(HTTTP_REQUEST.jsonResponse);
```

> The HTTTP_REQUEST.java:58 Line Contain :

```
 JSONObject listPrice = saleInfo.getJSONObject("listPrice");
```

Comment: Can you post the code for the `BookAdapter` class?

Comment: I think there is no error in the book adapter class as In place of the json  response I created :  ArrayList<BookStore> bookStoreArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        bookStoreArrayList.add(new BookStore("asdf","asdf","asdf","asdf",321,443.00,"asdf"));    then a whole range of list items were displayed in the screen

Comment: are you sure your view is not wrap content or something and its using the match parent. may be its just showing the first item only and rest is available in scroll. and also make sure you don't have adapter class with get items size return as 1

Comment: Since you said you "found all the data are correctly showing in the list but only 1 list item is displayed in the screen", I can only assume it's an adapter issue.

Comment: @vikaskumar thanks for the reply, the view is in match parent and when I am using this mock data : ArrayList<BookStore> bookStoreArrayList = new ArrayList<>(); 
      bookStoreArrayList.add(new BookStore("asdf","asdf","asdf","asdf",321,443.00,"asdf"));  then all the list items are showing in the screen

Comment: @DavidVelasquez   Got a  logcat error which I am adding in the question section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for posting the logcat error. That is the cause of your items not displaying on screen. After looking at the json data you provided, you need to do a null check on `listPrice` before processing it since some items in `saleInfo` do not have that field. So instead of this line:

`JSONObject listPrice = saleInfo.getJSONObject("listPrice");`

do:
`JSONObject listPrice = saleInfo.optJSONObject("listPrice");`

and then do a null check on `listPrice`:

```
Double amount = null;
String currencyCode = null;

if(listPrice != null) {
    amount = listPrice.getDouble("amount");
    currencyCode = listPrice.getString("currencyCode");
}
```

No need to add another inner try/catch. Also, you need to use the `Double` class since there is a possibility of having a null value, and also because your `Bookstore` constructor is passing that field.

If there are other fields that have the potential of not being in the json response, then you will need to add null checks on those JSONObjects as well.

Comment: The variables need to be declared outside. Otherwise, we will end up having a compilation error.

Comment: @ReazMurshed fixed

Comment: You misread the `logcat`. That's not the problem. **listPrice** not found under **saleInfo**. So, your solution produce the same error. Please correct it

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman  No I didn't misread it the problem was displayed there and now it is solved

Comment: @SHOONYA, I didn't tell you. I told DavidVelasquez. His solution is not correct that you fixed in your solution. I mentioned that

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman what do you mean? the problem was there needed to be a null check on `listPrice`. The OP has done that in his solution which has fixed the issue.

Comment: `JSONObject listPrice = saleInfo.getJSONObject("listPrice");` produce `JSONException: No value for listPrice` as there is not `key` like `listPrice`. You have to use `JSONObject listPrice = saleInfo.optJSONObject("listPrice");`

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman You are also right, Not only I had to check the if(listPrice != null) I also had to try and catch the listPrice under sale Info as it is else the error would still remain

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman ah I see. But that's weird because in the javadocs it says it returns null if key is not available, which makes sense, since then OP would need to add bunch of try/catches for every single field. Javadoc: https://processing.github.io/processing-javadocs/core/processing/data/JSONObject.html#getJSONObject-java.lang.String-

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman I was reading the wrong documentation I guess. On the Android docs site, I see it throws an exception if key is not found. Yeah OP should be using `optJSONObject("listPrice");` instead. Thanks for the clarification, I'll update the answer.

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman  I have updated the answer where I mentioned about your comment and used opt instead of get and now no need for adding try/catch blocks everywhere

Comment: @SHOONYA if this helped resolve your problem, why was the accepted answer removed?

Comment: @DavidVelasquez Oh Sorry, I didn't noticed that I accepted the ans

Answer (score 1):

Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/users/3851567/david-velasquez
for the answer.
And Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/users/2637449/md-asaduzzaman for pointing out the actual error for using opt instead of get.
After fixing that error I found more similar error which had no value assigned and I used optString, OptObject instead of getString, getJson and assigned a default value when the value is missing.

> Here are the changes that I made in the readFromJson method to solve
> the error:

```
   public static ArrayList<BookStore> readFromJson(String jsonObject) {
    ArrayList<BookStore> currentBookStore = new ArrayList<>();
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(jsonObject)) {
        return null;
    }
    try {
        double amount=0;
        String currencyCode = "Not Available";
        String textSnippet = "No Description Available";
        JSONObject root = new JSONObject(jsonObject);
        JSONArray items = root.getJSONArray("items");
        for (int i = 0; i < items.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject currentBook = items.getJSONObject(i);
            JSONObject volumeInfo = currentBook.getJSONObject("volumeInfo");
            String fTitle = volumeInfo.getString("title");
            String lTitle = volumeInfo.optString("subtitle");
            JSONArray author = volumeInfo.getJSONArray("authors");
            String authorName = author.getString(0);
            int PageCount = volumeInfo.getInt("pageCount");
            JSONObject saleInfo = currentBook.getJSONObject("saleInfo");

                JSONObject listPrice =saleInfo.optJSONObject("listPrice");
                if(listPrice != null) {
                    amount = listPrice.getDouble("amount");
                    currencyCode = listPrice.getString("currencyCode");
                             }
                JSONObject searchInfo = currentBook.optJSONObject("searchInfo");
                if (searchInfo!=null){
                    textSnippet = searchInfo.optString("textSnippet");
                }
            BookStore bookStore = new BookStore(fTitle, lTitle, authorName, textSnippet, PageCount, amount, currencyCode);


            currentBookStore.add(bookStore);
        }
    } catch (JSONException j) {
        Log.e("readFromJson Error", "error in reading the json response", j);
    }
    return currentBookStore;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks EveryOne for the response my reputation Increased to 50 , now I can comment to others questions.